# boxes homework sheet exams

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, tcolorbox, exercises

> I would like to create something like in the attached file.
>
> Any help will be appreciated.

by using the following commands:

- `Tikz`
- `tcolorbox`

note that i would prefer the box to be flexible in such a way that it can contain the text and the title exercice contains counter 
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{30mm}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=center,draw,thick,minimum width=\textwidth,inner sep=6mm] (titlebox)%
Soient $E=\{1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$ et A,B,C et D quatre parties de E définies par 
$$A=\{1,2,3,4 \},\ B=\{4,5,6,7 \}, C=\{1,3,5,7 \} $$
\begin{enumerate}
\item Calculer $\overightarrow{A}$
\item Calculer $\left( A\cup B\right) \cap \left( C\cup D\right) $
\end{enumerate}
\node[fill=white] W at (titlebox.north) {\bfseries \Huge Exercice};
\node (feat) at ([yshift=9mm]titlebox.north) {\textsc{\Large Exercice}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't require any direct tikz if you're using `tcolorbox`, which is extremely flexible. Using theorems and boxed titles as described in the `tcolorbox` manual, you might come up with something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems, breakable, skins}
\newtcbtheorem{example}% environment name
              {Example}% Title text
  {enhanced, % tcolorbox styles
  attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2.5mm},
  colback=white, colframe=black, colbacktitle=white, coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={size=small,colframe=white},
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  sharp corners=all,
  breakable
  }%
  {ex}% label prefix

\begin{document}

\begin{example}{Set Calculus}{sets}
  Soient $E=\{1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$ et $A$, $B$, $C$ et $D$ quatre parties de E d\'efinies par
  \[A=\{1,2,3,4 \},\ B=\{4,5,6,7 \}, C=\{1,3,5,7 \}. \]
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Calculer $\overline{A}$.
  \item Calculer $( A\cup B) \cap (C\cup D) $.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{example}

\noindent\textbf{Solution \ref{ex:sets}.}

\end{document}
```

[image: tcolorbox]

You should be able to put just about anything in the box (including other boxes), and it will even break across pages.

Comment: i have one problem with tcolorbox when i add ur code to my tex file the box colback=white turn out  Grey in pdf document

Comment: I don't know how to diagnose this problem without seeing the rest of your document. Maybe you could fix your snippet attempt above to (a) compile and (b) contain enough of the preamble you're using that adding my code to it reproduces your problem?

Comment: yes i added ur code (a) to my code (b) and i got   https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPGdN.jpg  should i ask new question ?

Comment: @Educ Since you initially said it works fine, I'm assuming that when you compile just the code I gave (without adding anything) you don't get the gray background. That means the issue is somewhere in your code, but since I don't have your code I can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @Educ If you post your code, then I might be able to help.